# Is the boot drive always /dev/sda

Tags: boot, grub, usb-drive

I have a computer with grub and linux installed on the internal hard drive. I also have a USB flash drive with linux that I boot into with grub on the internal hard drive. This causes the USB flash drive to always be /dev/sdb. I would like to know, if I have GRUB on the USB flash drive and boot to it via the BIOS menu, will it be seen as /dev/sda instead of /dev/sdb?

Comment: My computer that I'm typing on its booting from `/dev/sdb `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it depends on the disk. For new SSD via nvme for instance the disk is called `nvme0n1`. And if you have also a SATA disk you can also have a `sda` disk which is not the boot drive.

As far as I know nothing prevent the computer from booting on sdb or something else, you can by the way configure the bios to use one disk in particular for booting.

Comment: Oh, ok. Will I be able to assume then that if I plug it into a computer that had no other USBs plugged in, it will be /dev/sdb?

Comment: You can assume it, but there is no guarantee that it is the case. I am not sure how are decided the names (sda, sdb, etc. ) but it is the OS who does that. 
Also, the priority of boot is defined in the BIOS.

Comment: What is your use case ? What do you want to do with `sdb` ?

Comment: I have an LFS (Linux from scratch) installation on a flash drive, and the grub.cfg needs to point to a specific drive in order to boot the correct OS

Comment: Then my question is why do you have a grub on the USB ?

Comment: So that I can plug the USB into any computer I want and have it boot, because not all computers have GRUB

Comment: The problem is that grub must be installed, and during it's installation it listed the available OS and write them in the config file. Also Grub is not needed to boot, it is needed to boot on multiple systems (to choose which system to boot on). Maybe have a look to a bootable debian ISO.

Comment: If you want to boot on any computer, you just need to know the Bios Boot menu shortcut (F12, F11, Del, Esc, etc.) It can be  different on every manufacturer / models.

Comment: yeah, but without grub it says no bootable device

Comment: Maybe you need to format the usb drive partition to add the bootable flag to it then.

Comment: Is it a UEFI install or BIOS install? UEFI using gpt partitioning requires an ESP - efi system partition for grub's boot files. If old BIOS you can boot just by installing grub to MBR. But if using gpt and BIOS need a tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partiiton with bios_grub flag ( if using gparted).